# Looking for a CMS to publish online tutorials

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I want to create a site with tutorials on a specific topic.

The tutorials would include code samples (so I need code highlighting), pictures, screencasts, and files to download.

I would like to edit the pages easily, like on wikis, but also allow for comments like on blogs.

I don't want wiki-like community editing, and I want to update a given tutorial page continuously, like on wiki, but not like in the blog.

So which CMS should use?

Comment: framework or cms? big *difference* between the two.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "a web software" rather than framework. I want to put my tutorials on the web, improve them in future, and collect comments. And get the basic page layout, ability to include "code samples (so I need code highlighting), pictures, screencasts, and files to download", tags, comments etc. out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've updated the question to better reflect what you are looking for.

Comment: Isn't there sth more like Google Blogger than CMS, with which you don't need to bother much, just create an account, get some disk space, pay if you want more, and get all those features I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning to install software on a server with your own domain name, then the three biggest open-source CMSs are Drupal, Joomla and Wordpress. All three will do what you are asking for - WYSIWYG editing, comments, file management, a media library.

Wordpress is more focused on blogging, whereas Drupal and Joomla - while they can be used as blogs - are more general-purpose. Wordpress focuses on displaying content chronologically (i.e. most recent first), although it can be used to display content by categories. Although this is subjective, Wordpress is probably easier to use than either Drupal or Joomla.

On the other hand, you can go with a hosted service. Again Wordpress offer this with Wordpress.com, but there is also Blogger, LiveJournal. You can even do this with Facebook Pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Tiki CMS](http://tiki.org) as well.  It is a full-featured CMS with articles, wiki, file galleries, etc, but you get to pick the features you need and can activate others as needed.
Check out docs on [Tiki Essentials](http://twessentials.keycontent.org/)